# why backtrace info is corrupt after the thread run sleep?

Tags: c, gdb

I try to get the backtrace of all threads of a process.
I wrote a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int func_a(int *a)
{
    *a++;
    return 0;
}

void* test_thread(void* args)
{
    int a = 0;
    while(1) {
        func_a(&a);
        //sleep(1);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", a);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{  
    pthread_t pid = 0;
    pthread_create(&pid, NULL, test_thread, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pid, NULL, test_thread, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pid, NULL, test_thread, NULL);
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

then i ran the program,and execute
 `pidof ./1|xargs -n1 sudo gdb --batch -ex "thread apply all bt full" -p`
I saw the backtrace.(too many output i just pick some)

```
Thread 2 (Thread 0xb459db40 (LWP 25272)):
#0  func_a (a=0xb459d354) at 1.c:6
No locals.
#1  0x0804871f in test_thread (args=0x0) at 1.c:21
        a = 382337846
#2  0xb775bf72 in start_thread (arg=0xb459db40) at pthread_create.c:312
        __res = <optimized out>
        pd = 0xb459db40
        now = <optimized out>
        unwind_buf = {cancel_jmp_buf = {{jmp_buf = {-1216946176, -1269179584, 4001536, -1269181400, -56721544, -1538858626}, mask_was_saved = 0}}, priv = {pad = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, data = {prev = 0x0, cleanup = 0x0, canceltype = 0}}}
        not_first_call = <optimized out>
        pagesize_m1 = <optimized out>
        sp = <optimized out>
        freesize = <optimized out>
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "start_thread"
#3  0xb7691f8e in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:129
No locals.
```

But when I enable the sleep statement in test_thread function,it can't get the backtrace.

```
Thread 3 (Thread 0xb4d29b40 (LWP 26045)):
#0  0xb7716cf9 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.

Thread 2 (Thread 0xb4528b40 (LWP 26046)):
#0  0xb7716cf9 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

does anyone know why

thanks @Employed Russian to point out the defects.The enviroment is as follow:

- gcc version: 4.8.4
- gdb version: 7.7.1
- compile command: gcc -g 1.c -o 1 -lpthread -rdynamic
- ~/.gdbinit is not exist

I use ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but `*a++;` should be `(*a)++`. Otherwise you're incrementing the pointer, not what it points to.

Comment: `sleep()` blocks the process in the kernel. My guess is that you can't get a backtrace while the process is in the kernel.

Comment: @Barmar Sure you can. Try the test program on your own Linux machine, and observe perfectly good stack traces.

Comment: There are several possible reasons. The version of GCC and GDB used may matter. Compile line flags may matter. Contents of `~/.gdbinit` may matter. Please edit the question to provide additional details.

Comment: @barmar,thanks to pointer out the bug

Comment: @Employed Russian thanks to point out the defect, I had add the infomation in the question description

Comment: `-lpthread` just tells the *linker* to link the POSIX thread library. You also want to tell the *compiler* that the code actually *is*  multithreaded by specifying `-pthread` as well.